# Can cache-control affect Session.Timeout?

Tags: c#, .net

We have a .NET Framework web app where we use .ASPAUTH cookie and ASP.NET_SessionId for authenticated user.  Our Session.Timeout is set to 60 minutes in the IIS hosted web.config file.

Recently I follow the [recommendation of OWASP top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A3_2017-Sensitive_Data_Exposure.html) to prevent possible information exposure by Disable caching for response that contain sensitive data.

I did this by adding the following in the Web.config file of the web app.

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store" />
        <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
        <add name="Expires" value="0" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

The very next day I start getting call from some users (not all) that they got redirect to the log out page by simply clicking on links in our web application.  So I did what naturally comes to me is to roll back that change and off course that complains went a way gradually.

This puzzle me, as I don't know how http response caching directive could lead to invalidating a user session and log them out.  Even though I see the issue went away, there is no way for me to confirm that it was due to my roll back of these header values.

I know the Pragma and Expires are from Pre HTTP 1.1 so I plan to add the following back in and see if I have the log out issue again.

```
<add name="Cache-Control" value="private, max-age=3600, must-revalidate" />
```

Do you think they are related? I researched around and all I could come up is the cache control really affect how often the user request resource from server.  One factor I don't have control over is can something on the user's browser end that when combine with this Cache-Control directive can destroy their authenticated session?

Update: I see this refers briefly at [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).  However, they don't really go into the details.

[image]

Comment: Is the app hosted on IIS? The built-in caching modules never instruct client-side caching for dynamic and/or authenticated responses, no need to do anything.

Comment: Yes, it is hosted on IIS